# Why Excel Power Query is reading the data in different ways with same type(CSV)?

Tags: excel, powerquery

01.01.2024.csv

| Type | name |
| --- | --- |
| call | John |
| call | Jose |

03.01.2024.csv

| Type | name |
| --- | --- |
| call,John |  |
| call,Jose |  |

The file are same type(CSV) but after expanding the table from the data source it shows like that above.

I checked the file. I tried updating on different CSV. I made sure that the cells are correct. I Double checked that there's no special Character.

Comment: Most likely, the content of the csv files is not the same. Perhaps there are quote marks: `"call,John"`. Examine the csv files with a text editor, and post the contents from the text editor if you can't figure it out. It is possible that the PQ code is not the same, but unlikely. You can examine the first lines of the M-Code in the Advanced Editor.